# JavaFX TableView select row in Controller.initialize() is not drawn on application start

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I try to select a row in a TableView in Controller.initialize() method like this:

```
public class Controller {
public void initialize() {
 ...
 ObservableList<Operation> rows = FXCollections.observableArrayList(row1, row2);

 table.setItems(rows);
 table.getSelectionModel().select(row1);
 }
}
```

The application starts and the table row is unselected. If I touch scroll bar the selection appears. And stopping in debug mode during startup I can see it is actually selected.

What is wrong? How that can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

It were .css rules that specify the same color for an inactive (unfocused) selected row.